# Twilio adding custom attributes from studio into flex agent info bar

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using a "send to flex node" in my twilio studio application.
In this node I am passing:

```
{"verified": "{{flow.variables.verified}}", "accountid": "{{flow.variables.accountid}}"}
```

I have created a sample plugin but how can I modify it so that the existing agent info tab also displays those two parameters ? Maybe under CUSTOMER CONTEXT or in its own container?

I understand that they will need to be used as follows in the code :

```
${task.attributes.verified} and ${task.attributes.accountid}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a component that uses the [task context](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/add-component-context) so that it has access to the task object as one of its props. You can then add that component to the task info panel.

For example, here's an account component that displays the attributes you want:

```js
import React from "react";
import { withTaskContext } from "@twilio/flex-ui";

function AccountComponent({ task }) {
  return <div>
    <p>${task.attributes.verified} and ${task.attributes.accountid}</p>
  </div>;
}

export default withTaskContext(AccountComponent);
```

Then, in your main plugin file, within the `init` function, add the component to the task info panel. Using `sortOrder: -1` will place it at the top of the component.

```js
import React from "react";
import { FlexPlugin } from "flex-plugin";
import AccountComponent from "./components/AccountComponent";

const PLUGIN_NAME = "FlexTaskInfoPlugin";

export default class FlexTaskInfoPlugin extends FlexPlugin {
  constructor() {
    super(PLUGIN_NAME);
  }

  init(flex, manager) {
    flex.TaskInfoPanel.Content.add(
      <AccountComponent key="account-component"></CustomerName>,
      { sortOrder: -1 }
    );
  }
}
```